# Gnome Freezes often - how to find logs of the crash?

Tags: gnome, freeze, crash

PC specs:

- GA-990FXA-UD3 (rev. 4.1) mobo
- R9 390X gpu with padoka stable driver
- AMD FX-6350 cpu (IOMMU=soft in grub command line)
- 16GB ram
- Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome 3.28.2

Quite often, without repeatable or consistent trigger, the whole GUI freezes. It will happen while clicking things and while simply sitting there idle. After a minute or so, it flashes and reloads the desktop, all prior open apps are still open and running. Including audio that was playing.

I'd like to see the logs of what is causing it to crash but I don't know where to look. I'm about to switch to XFCE or Plasma bc it happens everyday at least once.

EDIT:

As requested by someone, here is some other info:

This command:
    sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
Output:
    F3

This Command:

```
ls -al /var/crash
```

output:

```
total 17556
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Dec  9 17:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root         4096 Aug  5 15:11 ..
-rw-r-----  1 bing     whoopsie  4834724 Dec  7 11:34 _opt_brave.com_brave_brave.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 bing     whoopsie        0 Dec  4 18:41 _opt_brave.com_brave_brave.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Dec  4 18:41 _opt_brave.com_brave_brave.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 bing     whoopsie    73034 Dec  5 22:40 _usr_bin_blueman-assistant.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 bing     whoopsie        0 Dec  5 22:11 _usr_bin_blueman-assistant.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Dec  5 22:11 _usr_bin_blueman-assistant.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 bing     whoopsie    78563 Dec  5 22:10 _usr_bin_blueman-manager.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 bing     whoopsie        0 Dec  4 21:22 _usr_bin_blueman-manager.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Dec  4 21:22 _usr_bin_blueman-manager.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 bing     whoopsie 12973514 Dec  7 12:50 _usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 bing     whoopsie        0 Dec  4 18:42 _usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Dec  4 18:42 _usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.uploaded
```

Comment: More than likely a GNOME Shell extension problem. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable ALL extensions, reboot, and see if it's more stable. Also, edit your question, and tell me the result of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` (should be F3 according to https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-990FXA-UD3-rev-41/support#support-dl-bios) and `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: `sudo journalctl --since="-10 minutes"` will help you. Do you have a swap file? `free` will tell.

Comment: @heynnema I made the edit. It will take some time to see if the extensions are the culprit. I'll try to remember to report back.

Comment: @waltinator I have 8gb of swap. Will that command be best used after a crash? If so, I'll try to remember to use it and output the results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit is gconnect (Gnome extension to use KDE connect with my android phone). Seems like notifications from my phone that are relayed to my computer, cause it to hiccup and is what is causing the crashing. Shame.

Comment: This was my issue too